# Canvas vs SVG on audio wave image interaction

Tags: javascript, audio, canvas, svg

I am building a tool to play audio where I will be [showing the wave image of the audio file](http://jsfiddle.net/e50o66m7/).
A audio image would look like this:

[image]

The UI will show the played area in another color as the not-yet-played area and also be able to zoom in a specific area.

**I could do this with a canvas,** and add a opacity div as a layer on top to show the played/unplayed area, changing the `left` position according to the position in the audio. An alternative would be to re-render everytime a update in position would ocurr to show different color in the played / unplayed area.

The zoom possibility in canvas would be a re-render also I supose.

**I could also do this in SVG**, and in this case the zoom would be probably easyer, and showing the played area would be a change in `stroke` color of the specific `path` or `line`.

**My question:**

Is this a scenario where "both options are valid", or should I use of the tecnologies over the other, and why?

Comment: I'm not sure using a change in stroke colour would work in svg, as you probably want it all to be one path, in which case you can't mix stroke colours. However, you could do the same as your canvas suggestion and have an overlay with opacity. Personally I would get writing and make most of the code as library agnostic as possible, so you can try swapping in other solutions and not have to refactor your code too much. I would use svg over canvas if you need fine interaction with the wave, but it doesn't sound like you need that, so I think either would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to use canvas in that case. 
Everything SVG has to offer over canvas e.g. DOM, hit detection, animation, filter etc. will not be used but will negatively contribute to the performance of your app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking this out. I refered to animating the played & unplayed area and also a zoom possibility. Could you detail more in which way you think `canvas` would be better than SVG in those functionalities?

Comment: @Rikard I agree with this answer. SVG will over complicate what should be a very simple rendering job. Yet OP this will depend on your skills as a programmer and how well you know either SVG or the Canvas API. This is particularly so because there are many traps when dealing with a large data set like a decoded sound stream. A 5 min stereo track at 44khz is 26million plus samples, not an easy thing to zoom and pan in real time. That is where you should be concentrating on, not what api will do the rendering.

Comment: @Blindman67 nice feedback thank you. Yes I am aware of those traps, also a zoom tools would probably need a debouncer or a throttle to avoid the zoom logic being called every step of the zoom. Where I lack experience is if a `loop` to generate the canvas in every zoom or play step is faster / better overall than a SVG path (for example with the waveform) and zoom in and out of that with SVG.

Comment: @Rikard I had a quick look at your code and the way you are doing it will never work in canvas. I am sure you are aware of that already by the time it takes to render out the waveform. Full screen canvas waveform with tracking and smooth zoom is well within the capability of the canvas. (SVG as well) On canvas use requestAnimationFrame to render. But you can not be drawing  100 lines per horizontal pixel. You need to pre sample the data. Do some performance tests so you know which methods are the quickest rendering solutions. And more, no room here to explain.

Comment: @Blindman67 yep, thanks. That was just a static test to ilustrate here.